# How to login into newrelic android app with heroku authentication data?

Tags: node.js, heroku, newrelic

I have some applications in heroku using nodeJS and newRelic and everything works fine.

Now I would like to track my applications on mobile using the newrelic android app.

How can i get the heroku authentication data used to login into newrelic to track the same applications without signup again?

Thanks